# Why do I get this error when I run my ASP.net MVC webapplication 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Error message IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AImBy.jpg)

When I run my project in Visual Studio I get this error. What could be the problem?

Comment: What information do you find in the Output window?

Comment: Failed to launch debug adapter 'chrome'.
Kan element niet vinden. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070490)


The program '' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
The program '[19460] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).